# Ubuntu 22.04 Disabling Wayland shows blank terminal on startup

Tags: nvidia, xorg, wayland

I'm trying to switch my display config from Wayland to Xorg - I need to use screensharing almost everyday for many platforms such as Zoom, Meets and Discord . . .

I have seen the most common solution is to change the gdm3 config file and uncomment the line with `Wayland=false`

I have tried this solution and the result is that my computer begins to start up then crashes before hitting the login screen - the only thing on my screen is a blank terminal screen.

Looking for some solutions and guidance please!

## My specs:

Model: MSI Raider GE76 12UE
OS: Ubuntu 22.04
GPU: GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q]

I've tried switching my graphics driver from nvidia-515 to xorg and with no success.

Comment: With your hardware and the 515 or later (not the -open versions) driver, at the login screen, after selecting the user to login, you should get a little gear in the bottom right corner. Click on that, and you should be offered 1)Ubuntu (the x choice) and 2)Ubuntu on wayland.  Note that the Nvidia case still defaults to Xorg. Without the hardware the choices are 1)ubuntu and 2)ubuntu on xorg. (defaulting to wayland).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I should add there is no gear icon either on my login page.